# If current category is child or grandchild of another category

Tags: wordpress

For example, I have this structure:

Inspiration > Men > CLothing > Jeans

And I am on the Jeans page, I want to write code to check with jeans is a grandchild of Men. How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about a CSS selector to target that, it would be

```
.Men > * > .Jeans
```

Asuming that men and jeans are classes